# Running services without sudo

Tags: cron, upstart, nohup, node.js

I want to run a nodeJS web server on a couple of machines which I don't have sudo access on. What would be a good way to do this?

The two requirements are:

1. running the service without being logged in (obviously)
2. automatically restarting if the machine is rebooted.

For 1., I've typically used `nohup` but is this a reasonable approach for production instances?

For 2., 
I can (hackily) add a `crontab` that starts the service, which will simply fail if it's already running. Is there a better way?

These servers are RHEL, but I'd prefer solutions that would also work for Ubuntu, if possible.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/173924/how-to-run-a-cron-job-using-the-sudo-command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `@reboot` as the `crontab` startup field to make relatively sure it hasn't already been started.

Comment: So reading between the lines, using `crontab` is not a bad way to run a service like this?

Comment: @SteveBennett Some would say that a non-admin running a service is "bad".  But inasmuch as doing so isn't bad in your case, cron isn't a bad way to run it.

Comment: An admin running a service is much worse. If you have any cron jobs starting services as root, I hope you demote them to `nobody` or some other user...